# Font Awesome 5 fa-github, fa-twitter, etc. not working (squares)

Tags: css, webpack, font-awesome

I have a website, setup with webpack. I added Font Awesome Pro and configured the global token for it. So the Pro Icons are working.

But some doesn't,  like `fa-github` or `fa-twitter`. And these are actually even free icons. A few days ago they worked.

Here's my code how I set everything up:

Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-light": "^5.0.9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular": "^5.0.9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid": "^5.0.9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts": "^1.0.5",
}
```

main.scss:

```
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts/webfonts";
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts/scss/fa-light.scss';
```

webpack:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid$': '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid/shakable.es.js',
      '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular$': '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/shakable.es.js',
      '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-light': '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-light/shakable.es.js'
    }
  },


<i class="fal fa-check"></i> // Does work
<i class="fal fa-github"></i> // Does not work
<i class="fal fa-twitter"></i> // Does not work
```

What am I missing? Do I have to import another CSS file for these? I didn't find any.

Edit: Added photo of folder structure:

[image]

Comment: can you show us the  image of your folder structure

Comment: you need to include webfonts folder also.. make sure you provided the correct path for webfonts

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! Image added. The paths should be correct. Everythings compiling in webpack and as mentioned the other icons are working (lika fa-check or fa-birthday-cake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively,

You can import Font Awesome icons the Javascript way.

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
import brands from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands'

fontawesome.library.add(brands)
```

---

You will need the `@fortawesome/font-awesome-pro-brands` package for this.

Use `<i class="fab fa-github"></i>` and `<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>`

You cannot use `fal` for the class since there are no social icons in the `font-awesome-pro-light` set.

See: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=github&s=light

Comment: Thanks for noting this with fal and fab!  I even copied some out of the documentation, but it still doesn't work.
@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-brands or @fortawesome/font-awesome-pro-brands don't exists. I just find the free-brands package.

I added the free-brands package to the resolve config for webpack. Do I have to import anything else in my main.scss? I can't find any scss file in the free-brands package..

Comment: Hi, have a look at my edited answer. You can import the fonts via Javascript way. I just use one pack as an example. Feel free to change accordingly to the icon packs that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I was just solving this not working "fa-github" icon issue in my Vuetify project and the solution was actually super simple:

```
fab fa-github
```

Or the long version:

```
fa-brands fa-github
```

It's actually mentioned in the icon description in the webpage that this is a "brands" class icon so you need to add the `fab`  prefix.